# What is the use of AutoDiscoverURL?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-3.0

While analyzing a program I saw a function called AutoDiscoverURL !! I have googled it, unfortunately not able to figure it out.

Comment: https://www.google.com.tr/search?q=AutoDiscoverURL

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd634273(v=exchg.80).aspx

Comment: These don't overly make sense to me. Whilst the text is there, what does it mean?

Answer (score 3):

The Autodiscover property will work out the Service URL using just the emal address passed in. If the AutoDiscover redirects then the autodiscover will fail.

You can use it to find the endpoint if you don't know it.

```
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010); 
service.Url //Null
service.AutodiscoverUrl("Dean.Meehan@company.ie", (discoverURL) => true);
service.Url //https://exchange.example.com/ews/exchange.asmx
```

Note:I use the lamba `(discoverURL) => true` to always accept the url, if your getting untrusted emails then you may want to validate the url returned before running the discovery.

Answer (score 0):

The [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd634273(v=exchg.80).aspx) gives the answer straight away:

> Initializes the Url property to the Exchange Web Services (EWS)
>   endpoint for a specified email address by calling the Autodiscover
>   service.
>
> **Remarks:**
>
> If an Autodiscover server returns a redirect HTTP status code, this
>   method will generate an AutodiscoverLocalException with the Message
>   property set to a string such as "Autodiscover blocked a potentially
>   insecure redirection to
>   https://autodiscover.contoso.com/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml. To
>   allow Autodiscover to follow the redirection, use the
>   AutodiscoverUrl(string, AutodiscoverRedirectionUrlValidationCallback)
>   overload." This exception is generated for all redirect responses,
>   regardless of the validity of the URL returned in the redirect
>   response.